# how to access to event object propereties

Tags: php, events

I want to access for particular information which is contained in event object.

```
public function init()
{
    parent::init();

    craft()->on('entries.saveEntry', function(Event $event) 
    {

        var_dump($event->params['entry']);
    });
}
```

it dumps info (brining a needed part)

```
     ......
["_preppedContent":"Craft\BaseElementModel":private]=>
  array(1) {
    ["tweet"]=>
    array(23) {
      ["created_at"]=>
      string(30) "Thu Nov 13 09:15:40 +0000 2014"
      ["id"]=>
      float(5.3282410346476E+17)
      ["id_str"]=>
      string(18) "532824103464763392"
      ["text"]=>
      string(115) "'The innovation insight you didn't get from Forbes' great blog by @LydiaRagoonanan @nesta_uk http://t.co/PImPVvWeAv"
      ["source"]=>
      string(63) "Hootsuite"
      ["truncated"]=>
      bool(false)
```

How can I extract `text`, `id_str` information?
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I assume both `text` and `id_str` are custom fields?

```
$event->params['entry']
```

Is an [EntryModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/classreference/models/EntryModel), so you should be able to do this:

```
$entry = $event->params['entry'];
$idString = $entry->id_str;
$text = $entry->text;
```

Comment: I can't do so, but I found a way $event->params['entry']->getFieldValue('tweet')['text']

Comment: Oh, you must be using a plugin that populates 'tweet', then.

Answer (score -1):

It's an array, so:

```
$entry = $event->params['entry'];
$text = $entry['text'];
```